# Convert string coming from variable into another variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have a string that I get from a map and I want to convert it into a variable, Here is a complete ex:
1. I have the following list of items:

```
const Fruits = [
  {
    name: 'Apple',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    shape: 'apple',
  },
  {
    name: 'Banana',
    width: 10,
    height: 100,
    shape: 'banana',
  },
]
```

```
const Fruits1 = [
  {
    name: 'Orange',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    shape: 'orange',
  },
  {
    name: 'Lemon',
    width: 10,
    height: 100,
    shape: 'lemon',
  },
]
```

2. And a second list of items:

```
const items = [
  {
    name: 'Fruits',
    abbr: 'A',
  },
  {
    name: 'Fruits1',
    abbr: 'b',
  },
]
```

3. I want to convert the string "item.name" into "Fruits" in order to pass the const Fruits as a list to the "newList" variable like this:

```
const listItems = items.map((item, index) =>
    <Item
      key={index}
      newList={item.name} // I need this one to become variable and not to evaluate into string
      {...props}
    />
  );
```

Any suggestion on how to do it?

I'm expecting this result:

```
const listItems = items.map((item, index) =>
    <Item
      key={index}
      newList={Fruits} // I need this one to become variable and not to evaluate into string
      {...props}
    />
  );
```

N.B: item.name will be "Fruits" for the first item, then "Fruits1" for the second one and so on...

Comment: But `item.name` will be `Apple` not `Fruits`.

Comment: do you want items to be like `{
    abbr: "b" ,
    Fruits: "Banana"
  }` or `{
    abbr: "A" ,
    Fruits: {
      name: 'Apple',
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      shape: 'apple',
    }
  }`

Comment: item.name will be "Fruits" for the first item, then "Fruits1" for the second one and so on..., I edited my question to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the name of the items to get data from the Fruit collection. this is a simple way to do that.

```
const listItems = items.map((item, index) =>
  <Item
  key={ index }
  newList = { Fruits.find(fruit => fruit.name === item.name) } // I need this one to become variable and not to evaluate into string
  { ...props }
  />
);
```

Comment: Actually I want to passe the "Fruits" as a variable to "newList", which means I want "newList" to be a list of the items of "Fruits".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const Fruits = [
  {
    name: 'Apple',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    shape: 'apple',
  },
  {
    name: 'Banana',
    width: 10,
    height: 100,
    shape: 'banana',
  },
]

const items = [
  {
    name: 'Apple',
    abbr: 'A',
  },
  {
    name: 'Banana',
    abbr: 'b'}
    ]
 

const result  =  items.map((ele, i) => ({key:i, newList:Fruits.find(r=>r.name===ele.name) ,...ele}) ); 

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is only if you have two arrays: Fruits and Fruits1, this is what I understood from your question you need a list. hope I answered your question.

```js
const listItems = items.map((item, index) => {
      const Fruits = Fruits.find(fruit => fruit.name === item.name);

      if (!Fruits) {
        Fruits = Fruits1.find(fruit => fruit.name === item.name);
      }
      return (
        <Item
          key={index}
          newList={Fruits} // I need this one to become variable and not to evaluate into string
        />
      );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to rename a key in `items` JSON object.

You can try this to do that,

```
items.forEach(item=>{
  item.Fruits = item.name
  delete item.name
})
```

Input:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Apple',
    abbr: 'A',
  },
  {
    name: 'Banana',
    abbr: 'b',
  },
]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    abbr: "A" ,
    Fruits: "Apple"
  }
  {
    abbr: "b" ,
    Fruits: "Banana"
  }  
]
```